# Is $ x^3-x^2 -1 $ reducible in $\mathbb Z_5[x]/(x^3-x^2-1) = \mathbb Z_5(u) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Let $F=\mathbb Z_5[x]/(x^3-x^2-1)=\mathbb Z_5(u)$, $u=[x]$.

a) Is $ p(x) = x^3-x^2 -1 $ reducible over $F$?
We found that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$, but we are not sure about $F$.

b) We found that a basis for $F$ over $\mathbb Z_5$ is $\{1,u,u^2\}$ and we want to express $\frac{1}{1+u}$ in this basis.

Comment: a) It seems tricky, since that element is actually 0. What is your definition of ireducible?

Comment: by irreducible i mean can not be factoried into non-constant polynomials with lesser degrees

Comment: So, p(x) is a polynomial in $F[x]$?. I

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: I still think this is confusing. Are you looking $p(x)$ as polynomial in the variable $x$, i.e. in $F[x]$? or are you considering $[p(x)]=p(u)=0$ in $F$?

Comment: the last one, so we realized it is not reducible

Comment: Because if is the first one they should have use another variable, like $p(X)=X^3-X^2-1$

Comment: So, You weren't using  the definition of irreducible polynomial that you mentioned, you were using the definition of irreducible element in an integral domain (in fact $F$ is a field) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)
$p(x) = 0$ (or, more rigorously, $[p(x)] = [0]$) in $F$. Is that reducible?

b)
I think the easiest way to do that is to use the extended Euclidean algorithm in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$ to find polynomials $f, g$ such that
$$
f(x)(1+x) + g(x)(x^3 - x^2-1) = 1
$$
Then projecting this equality down to $F$ we find $f(u)(1+u) = 1$, which means that $f(u)$ is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: okei, that makes a lot of sence, we had something similar for b) but we can't figure out f(u) from the above equation $f(u)(1+u) = 1$. How would you solve that?

Comment: @Sander You don't. $f(u)(1+u)= 1$ is a result. What you want to do is find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as described above.